# If $f(x)=\frac{e^{\tan x} -e^x+\ln (\sec x +\tan x)-x}{\tan x -x}$ is a continuous function at $x=0$, find $f(0)$

Tags: limits, functions, continuity, limits-without-lhopital

Using L’Hospital will provide the answer, the process is long and tedious, so I generally like to avoid it in such questions. But I am not able to find an alternative. Can I get a hint for this?

Comment: Maybe series expansion helps (even though this is essentially equivalent to l'Hospital),

Comment: You can show using power series expansion around the origin that $$
f(x) = \frac{3}{2} + x + \mathcal{O}(x^2 ).
$$ Thus, if you define $f(0)=\frac{3}{2}$, $f(x)$ becomes a continuous function in a neighbourhood of the origin.

Comment: Using LHospital is also fine. You just use it once. First split the fraction into two separating exponential part with the rest. The fraction containing exponential part tends to $1$ and the other fraction tends to $1/2$ via single use of LHospital Rule. Done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the function $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$, then $f(0)=L=\lim_{x]ro 0} f(x)$.
$$f(x)=\frac{e^{\tan x} -e^x+\ln (\sec x +\tan x)-x}{\tan x -x}$$
$$L=\lim_{x\to 0} \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{\tan x}-e^x}{\tan x-x}+\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(\sec x+\tan  x)-x}{\tan x-x}$$
Using $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{e^z-1}{z}=1$
$$\implies 1+\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(\tan(x/2+\pi/4)-x}{\tan x- x}$$
Use $\ln(1+z)=z-z^2/2+z^3/3+...$, then
$$\implies L= 1+\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+\tan(x/2)-\ln(1-\tan(x/2))-x}{\tan x- x}$$
Use $\ln(1+z)=z-z^2/2+z^3/3+...$, then
$$\implies L=1+\lim_{x \to +...0}\frac{2(\tan(x/2)+(1/3)\tan^3(x/2)+...)-x}{\tan x- x}$$
Next, using $\tan z=z+z^3/3+...$, when $z$ is very small, wr get
$$\implies L=1+\lim_{x \to +...0}\frac{2(x/2+(x/2)^3/3+(1/3)[(x/2)+.(x/2)^3/3+..)]^3-x}{\tan x- x}$$
$$\implies L=1+\lim_{x \to +...0}\frac{2]x/2+(x/2)^3/3+(1/3)(x/2)^3+O(x^4)]-x}{\tan x- x}$$
$$\implies L=1+\lim_{x \to +...0}\frac{(x+x^3/6+...)-x}{x^3/3+O(x^5)}$$
Finally, we get $$L=\frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: I didn’t understand what you did in the second last line

Comment: @Aditya I have added more terms to clarify. Please see.